# Not being able to play videos in android studio

Tags: android, video, android-emulator

I have been trying to display a video in my emulator, but seems to encounter a problem where it is not showing up when the button is pressed. This is my code:

public class VideoView extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_view);
    android.widget.VideoView videoView=findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    String videoPath= "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.fyp;
    Uri uri= Uri.parse(videoPath);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
}
```

}

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
videoview.start();
```

To make the video work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).